# C++, file i/o...i have a .txt file and i have to scan it for exons and introns from it and write them to separate files

Tags: c++, arrays, string, file, file-io

program will sequentially read the DNA data from the input ﬁle and as it encounters exons and introns itwill write them out into separate ﬁles. The ﬁrst exon discovered will be written into exon1.txt, the second exon discovered will be written into exon2.txt, and so on... Similarly, the ﬁrst intron discovered will be written into intron1.txt, the second intron discovered will be written into intron2.txt, and so on...

An exon is a sequence of codons that always starts with the codon ATG and ends with one of the following codons: TAA, TGA, or TAG. Any sequence that does not start or stop with these codons is an intron .While scanning the data for exons and introns, only scan forward and look for non-overlapping exons and introns. If an exon start symbol (ATG) is encountered and another ATG is encountered before one of the stop codons are encountered, it does not mean a new exon has started.

i know how to read from a file, and i have already stored it in a global array. arrays much preferable, i could use strings too.

```
const int MAX_DNA = 50000;
char dnaData[MAX_DNA];


int readFromDNAFile(string fileName) {
 int returnValue = 0;

 ifstream fileHandle;
 fileHandle.open(fileName.c_str());

 if( fileHandle.good() ) {
  char nucleotide;
  int counter = 0;
  while( fileHandle >> nucleotide ) {
   dnaData[counter] = nucleotide;
   counter++;
  }
 returnValue = counter;

 }

 fileHandle.close();
 return returnValue;
}
```

i really have no idea how to implement what to do next, im sure i have to use a loop for naming the txt files for exons and introns, then another loop maybe for scanning and storing it ..

```
void readFiles(string filename){
  for(int i = 0; i < numFiles; i++) {
       //ill open up the file here to read 
            for(int j = 0; j < numCodons; j++) {
```

any effort will be appreciated, thankyou.

Comment: So this file is essentially a stream of ATCG (one line?), and you need to parse them out from that stream? (ie new lines or other delimiters don't indicate the start of a new exon?)

Comment: Yes , the text file is  only one line full of nucleotides ATCG.

Answer (score 0):

```
"im sure i have to use a loop for naming the txt files for exons and introns"
```

You said you need to create two files for introns and exons so you do not really need to have loop.

```
int main(){
    ifstream dna("dna.txt");
    ofstream exons("exons.txt");
    ofstream introns("intron.txt");
    while(!dna.eof()){
        string current_line;
        dna >> current_line;
        //if (line belongs to exons){
        // exon1 << current_line  
        //}

        //else(belongs to introns){
        // introns << current_line
        //}
    }

    //close files
}
```

would that not be ok?
I don't see why you need to store the data in an array.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you have no other delimiters other than the exon start/end codons - ie new lines etc aren't significant?

I'm guessing you're planning to store the data in an array during processing since if you start an exon but don't finish it would count as an intron?

But you don't need to store all the data for this in memory - just keep two file handles open.  Leave one at the start of the current exon, and use the other to scan forwards.  When you get to the end of the exon, you can then output it to it's file.  Introns can be immediately output to the other file.